# The specified parameter 'Datastore' expects a single value, but your name criteria 'xxX-xx-xxx-xxx-LUN002' corresponds to multiple values

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I need to Move-VM from one datastore to another datastore on the same host. Moving from TESTVM_india to xxX-xx-xxx-xxx-LUN002
While moving i am getting error message like below

```
Move-VM : 10/27/2018 1:25:03 PM    Move-VM    The specified parameter 'Datastore' expects a single value, but your name criteria 'xxX-xx-xxx-xxx-LUN002' corresponds to multiple values. 
At C:\Users\suganthanraj\Desktop\DS_Migration.ps1:130 char:1
+ Move-VM -VM $VMtoMove.VMName -Datastore "$VMMoveToDS" -VMotionPriority 
High
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (System.Collecti...dObjectInterop]:List`1) [Move-VM], VimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_ObnSelector_SelectObjectByNameCore_MoreResultsThanExpected,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.MoveVM

 Move-VM : 10/27/2018 1:25:20 PM    Move-VM        Either Destination or Datastore must be specified.    
 At C:\Users\suganthanraj\Desktop\DS_Migration.ps1:130 char:1
 + Move-VM -VM $VMtoMove.VMName -Datastore "$VMMoveToDS" -VMotionPriority High
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-VM], InvalidArgument
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Core_MoveVm_TryValidateParameterList_InvalidArgument,VMware.VimAutomation.ViCore.Cmdlets.Commands.MoveVM
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Maybe you have multiple connections open? Try `$defaultVIServers` and check if you get more than one entry back.
If so, that could be the problem, so close all other connections before calling the `Move-VM` cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PowerCLI 11, there is a known issue with Move-VM where it is requiring the "Destination" parameter to be specified.

Update your code to be the following and you should be fine:

```
Move-VM -VM $VMtoMove.VMName -Datastore "$VMMoveToDS" -VMotionPriority High -Destination $VMtoMove.VMHost
```